# Structure of a binary tree

Tags: c#, tree, regression, binary-tree, ml.net

**What i am trying to do:**

I want to display a tree.

**What i have done:**

I used [ML.net](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet) to train a Decision Tree Model using the random forrest algorithm.

The random forrest algorithm results in multiple regression trees, which i want to display.

When i aquire the tree list i get them in the following format:

```
leaf_num=20

split_feature=818 315 1707 1866 829 315 958 1682 1669 934 1794 1708 1274 1876 219 1892 557 38 755

split_gain=53.6443 26.8314 26.0605 25.312 24.9156 23.8195 26.0324 20.622 19.2891 19.2309 18.7427 17.5442 17.5224 16.147 15.3396 14.6873 14.3071 18.8269 14.2999
threshold=-0.001959169982001185 -0.0063232299871742717 -0.018274550326168534 -0.023883100599050518 -0.0033916500397026535 -0.0086862500756978971 0.0057975498493760833 -0.024933900684118267 0.025956150144338611 0.032694099470973022 -0.02218380011618137 0.018020399846136573 0.029140749946236614 -0.034148199483752244 0.0075621248688548812 0.02500609960407019 0.0055113600101321944 0.012193250004202129 0.018237499520182613

left_child=3 4 14 11 12 15 10 -4 13 -9 -7 -1 -2 -6 -3 -5 -12 -18 -8
right_child=1 2 7 5 8 6 18 9 -10 -11 16 -13 -14 -15 -16 -17 17 -19 -20

leaf_value=0.74074074074073915 0.34995047870584339 0.22257551669316322 -0.78431372549019063 -0.61827023271969384 0.6299212598425189 -0.45209903121636041 -0.68965517241379315 0.55182171913689448 0.59405940594059359 -0.78212290502792992 0.36304961678096054 -0.58823529411764608 -0.65789473684210453 -0.42461317020510986 -0.71428571428571386 0.19801980198019786 -0.3720106288751106 0.78853046594981979 0.031796502384737663
leaf_count=29 121 25 8 115 10 37 59 226 16 7 99 8 12 111 20 16 45 11 25
internal_value=0 0.963751 1.81717 -0.900576 0.0592242 -1.18872 -0.521437 2.3387 -1.13736 2.55618 0.291424 2.2605 1.29168 -1.68372 -0.974314 -2.59225 0.902294 -0.712251 -2.37643
internal_count=1000 556 286 444 270 407 276 241 137 233 192 37 133 121 45 131 155 56 84
shrinkage=0.2
```

*the containing class of ML.net is [RegressionTree.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/src/Microsoft.ML.FastTree/TreeEnsemble/RegressionTree.cs)*

From my understanding `left_child` and `right_child` are `LteChild` and `GtChild`, all of these arrays have the length of the *maximum node count* without the leafs (so if there are 20 leafs the length is 19).

`split_feature` is the data column of the feature which is used.

I think the negative values are leafs.

**My problem:**

Unfortunatly i fail to construct a node based tree like this

```
     O
    / \
   O   O
  / \ / \
 L  L L  L
```

because i do not understand how the values of the array are ordered.

**UPDATE:**

As always, when you ask others for help it doesn't take long to get another promising idea yourself:

i dug deeper into the code of ML.net and i think i found a clue (line 856 for those who are interested).

My guess is that there has to be a variable as a counter such as `int node`

this counter starts on `0`

to get the splitting column one needs to get `SplitFeatures[node]`

the child nodes would be `LteChild[node]` (LesserThanEqualChild) and `GtChild[node]` (GreaterThan)

and so on.

**UPDATE2:**

i think i got this right

Structured data:

```
split_feature=  818 315 1707 1866 829 315 958 1682 1669 934 1794 1708 1274 1876 219 1892 557 38  755

                0   1   2    3    4   5   6   7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14  15   16  17  18
left_child=     3   4   14   11   12  15  10 -4    13  -9  -7   -1   -2   -6   -3  -5   -12 -18 -8
right_child=    1   2   7    5    8   6   18  9   -10  -11  16  -13  -14  -15  -16 -17   17 -19 -20
```

once i programmed a solution i will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on the ML.net github page and got a good answer from Ivanidzo4ka of Microsoft.

The Link to the Issue: [Link to github](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/521)